# Locate the positions (row and column) of missing elements in a database using R

Tags: r

The code below tells me how many NA's I have in my database and in which columns they appear. However, I wish to identify their positions. Please assist.

```
apply(apply(ncv, 2, is.na), 2, sum)

Identity Number      Student No          Course           Level 
             4               4               4               4 
        Tuition          Campus 
            31               4
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. You might be looking for `which` with `arr.ind = TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still a little flummoxed when it comes to making my example reproducible. Sorrry

Answer (score 3):

An example, create a data.frame with two `NA` values:

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2[2, 3] <- NA
mtcars2[4, 6] <- NA
```

`which` is your friend here, no `apply` needed:

```
which(is.na(mtcars2), arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Gives:

```
               row col
Mazda RX4 Wag    2   3
Hornet 4 Drive   4   6
```